# How do I plot the length of the petals for one variable for the "IRIS" data?

Tags: r, plot, norm

So I extracted the values from the IRIS data and the species in this data are
Setosa,Versicolor, and virginica. Now I want to make a qq plot of the petal length, but I want it to be seperate for each other. So like I want the petal length of juwt the setosa, and then just the versicolor.

I tried qqnorm(setosa$Petal.length). I can't find it online?

Comment: Its easy using ggplot see the bottom example: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_qq.html

Comment: Like `par(mfrow=c(2,2)); lapply( split(iris$Petal.Length, iris$Species), qqnorm )`?

Comment: I can't use ggplot, I have to use a qqnorm.. do you know how to just graph the Petal length of the Sertosa species. I just need the petal length of that one species plotted... I can't use outside stuff.

Comment: nobody knows how to do this? must be more complex that I thought x_x

Answer (score 1):

For the one species "setosa":

```
qqnorm(iris[iris$Species=="setosa","Petal.Length"])
```

Otherwise, for all the species:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
lapply(unique(iris$Species), function(x){ 
       qqnorm(iris[iris$Species==x,"Petal.Length"],main=x) })
```

Comment: Thank you so much you are literally a god... works perfectly, and makes complete sense.

Comment: Do you by any chance know how to change the title of the graph so its easier to know which one is sertosa, is there a way to do that?

Comment: The `main=...` specify the title of the plot. Please mark it answer if it satisfy your question.